# Combine ListModelMixin with APIView to show pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I want to show the pagination feature in my API and I am using `APIView` with multiple serializers.
I know it is very easy to show pagination with `ListView`.
 
I have seen somewhere that combining `ListModelMixin` and `APIView` works but if my code is as follows:

```
class ListModelMixin(object):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serilaizer.data)

class ItemsAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Return a list of all devices of this user.
        """
        reply = {}
        try:
            products = BaseItem.objects.owned_items().filter(owner=request.user)
            reply['data'] = OwnedItemSerializer(products, many=True).data

            items = BaseItem.objects.dev_items().filter(owner=request.user)
            reply['data'].extend(ItemSerializer(items, many=True).data)

        except:
            reply['data'] = []
        return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

How can I combine them so I can get paginated results? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: While i get the gist of what you are trying to do, I would recommend that the `ItemAPIView` not try to query data the way you are doing. The view should provide the `queryset` and the rest should be upto the serializer. If you can provide the kind of o/p you are looking for along with the `serializer` definitions, a definite solution can be posted.

Comment: The output i am looking for is just the pagination feature. If i do /api/v1/items ?page=1 i should get 10 items per page.

Comment: The two serializer used are one is for owned items and another is of dev items.

Comment: @ShikharChauhan Did you understand the use of two serializer in my case?

Comment: No, It is hard to tell without the serializer code.

Comment: @ShikharChauhan then i think i have to show the model either.

Comment: Hey, @pythonBeginner I was wondering, did you find any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 3):

First things first, what you are currently doing is too complex without reason.

In order to achieve a "paginatable" queryset, it is preferred to change your  `owned_items()` and `dev_items()` in simple filter combinations, rather than model methods. To clarify by example:

```
products = BaseItem.objects.filter(owner=request.user, owned=True)
```

instead of

```
products = BaseItem.objects.owned_items().filter(owner=request.user)
```

That way, you can produce a single queryset which will be easier to paginate:

```
user_items = BaseItem.objects.filter(
                 Q(owner=request.user, owned=True) |
                 Q(owner=request.user, dev=True)
             )
```

**Note 1:** You can simplify things further if you like, but that gets out of scope of your question. As food for thought, check this out:

```
user_items =  BaseItem.objects.filter(owner=request.user).distinct()
```

**Note 2:** You should use a single serializer for a single model because what you are doing adds complexity without benefit (high risk-low reward situation)

---

With the above mentioned and assumed:

There are some ways to achieve what you want here:

1. By utilizing [GeneriAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) and [ListModelMixin](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listmodelmixin) you can refactor your class in such a way to have a `.list()` method with auto-pagination:

   ```
   from rest_framework import mixins, generics

   class ItemsAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView,):
       permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
       pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS
       serializer_class = OwnedItemSerializer

       # You can define .get in here if you really need it.
       # You can also override .list to add specific functionality
   ```
2. If you don't want to use the above, and you want to keep your `APIView`, then you can keep your `get` method and provide pagination for it as mentioned in this [Q&A example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670648/how-to-use-pagination-in-a-non-generic-view-viewset):

   ```
   class ItemsAPIView(APIView):
       permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
       pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS
       serializer_class = MyNewUnifiedSerializerClass

       def get(self, request):
           user_items =  BaseItem.objects.filter(
                             owner=request.user
                         ).distinct()
           page = self.paginate_queryset(user_items)

           if page is not None:
               serializer = self.serializer_class(page, many=True)
               return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

           serializer = self.get_serializer(user_items, many=True)
           return Response(serializer.data)

       # Now add the pagination handlers taken from 
       #  django-rest-framework/rest_framework/generics.py

       @property
       def paginator(self):
           """
           The paginator instance associated with the view, or `None`.
           """
           if not hasattr(self, '_paginator'):
               if self.pagination_class is None:
                   self._paginator = None
               else:
                   self._paginator = self.pagination_class()
               return self._paginator

        def paginate_queryset(self, queryset):
            """
            Return a single page of results, 
            or `None` if pagination is disabled.
            """
            if self.paginator is None:
                return None
            return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(
                       queryset, 
                       self.request, 
                       view=self
                   )

        def get_paginated_response(self, data):
            """
            Return a paginated style `Response` object 
            for the given output data.
            """
            assert self.paginator is not None
            return self.paginator.get_paginated_response(data)
   ```