# How to use Pagination in a Non-Generic View/Viewset?

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

**Prologue:**

I have seen this question arising in more than one posts:

- [Django Rest Framework - APIView Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830779/django-rest-framework-apiview-pagination/)
- [Pagination not working in DRF APIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159208/pagination-not-working-in-drf-apiview/)
- [Django rest framework global pagination parameters not working for ModelViewSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722221/django-rest-framework-global-pagination-parameters-not-working-for-modelviewset)

and can also be applied here:

- [Combine ListModelMixin with APIView to show pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163653/combine-listmodelmixin-with-apiview-to-show-pagination/)

I have composed an example on SO Documentation to unify my answers in the above questions but since the Documentation will get shutdown on August 8 2017, I will follow the suggestion of [this widely upvoted and discussed meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation/354302#354302) and transform my example to a self-answered post.

Of course I would be more than happy to see any different approach as well!!

---

**Question:**

I want to use a Non Generic View/Viewset (eg: [`APIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views)) on a Django Rest Framework project.
As I read on the [pagination documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/):

> Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic views or viewsets. If you're using a regular `APIView`, you'll need to call into the pagination API yourself to ensure you return a paginated response. See the source code for the `mixins.ListModelMixin` and `generics.GenericAPIView` classes for an example.

Can I still continue using a non generic view/viewset?
How can I implement pagination on it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We can find a solution without the need to reinvent the wheel:

1. Let's have a look on how the `generics` pagination is implemented:
   [django-rest-framework/rest_framework/generics.py](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L155).
   That is exactly what we are going to use to our view as well!
2. Let's assume that we have a global pagination setup like the following in:
    
   `settings.py`:

   ```
   REST_FRAMEWORK = {
       'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 
           'rest_framework.pagination.DESIRED_PAGINATION_STYLE',
       'PAGE_SIZE': 100
   }
   ```
3. In order not to bloat our view/viewset's code, we can create a custom mixin to store our pagination code:

   ```
   class MyPaginationMixin(object):

       @property
       def paginator(self):
           """
           The paginator instance associated with the view, or `None`.
           """
            if not hasattr(self, '_paginator'):
                if self.pagination_class is None:
                    self._paginator = None
                else:
                    self._paginator = self.pagination_class()
            return self._paginator

        def paginate_queryset(self, queryset):
            """
            Return a single page of results, or `None` if pagination 
            is disabled.
            """
            if self.paginator is None:
                return None
            return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(
                queryset, self.request, view=self)

        def get_paginated_response(self, data):
            """
            Return a paginated style `Response` object for the given 
            output data.
            """
            assert self.paginator is not None
            return self.paginator.get_paginated_response(data)
   ```
4. Then on `views.py`:

   ```
   from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
   from rest_framework.views import APIView

   from my_app.mixins import MyPaginationMixin

   class MyView(APIView, MyPaginationMixin):
       queryset = OurModel.objects.all()
       serializer_class = OurModelSerializer
       pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS 

       # We need to override the get method to insert pagination
       def get(self, request):
           ...
           page = self.paginate_queryset(self.queryset)
           if page is not None:
               serializer = self.serializer_class(page, many=True)
               return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
   ```

And now we have an `APIView` with pagination.

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'paginate_queryset'. im getting this error

Comment: @Thameem It's a bit difficult to help you without some code to see what you have done... If the issue persists, consider making a question here on SO.

Comment: @thanks for your message i missed this response  return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data). thanks. its working now

Comment: @JohnMoutafis I've changed the 'PAGE_SIZE' to 10, but it gives me 100 items

Comment: This page is still saving lives to this day.

Comment: By the way, Have you tried combining this (APIView, pagination) with filters in Django? That is filtering (filter search) multiple fields of a model in Django

Comment: @OpeyemiOdedeyi I have tried using the `django-filters` module: django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master and it worked fine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048156/django-filter-use-paginations/44541540#44541540 (updated comment with a corresponding link)